# Preg Replace / Preg Match for href in html link?

Tags: php, regex

Anybody have a regular expression to replace the following code:

```
<a href="originalLink">hi</a>
```

with:

```
<a href="newLink">hi</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) example:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all links 
$anchors = $html->find('a');

$count = count($anchors);

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
    $anchors[$i]->href = 'someLink.html';
}
```

If you know the `href` of the anchor you want to replace, do something like:

```
$html->find('a[href=something]', 0)->href = 'someLink.php';
```

Comment: Ditto - this will be far more reliable than parsing HTML with a regex. The grammar of HTML is simply too complex and too loosely enforced for real-world regular expressions to handle all cases.

Comment: Is file_get_html a real method? I can't find it anywhere. What type of object does it return?

Comment: I believe it comes from simple html :-)