# Replacing image src in HTML tags?

Tags: php, regex

I want to use regex to replace `src` html attributes. The HTML is not malformed and fortunately takes the same form in all the pages in the database - i.e.

```
<img src="http://x.y/z/1.png" />
```

I have code that works fine if there's only one image in the page. I want to know the best way to replace multiple images, as this one will replace all the image tags with the same string.

```
$result = $s->db_query("SELECT reviewFullText as f FROM reviews WHERE reviewsID = 155");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $body = stripslashes(html_entity_decode($row['f'], ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    preg_match_all('/<img.*?(src\=[\'|"]{0,1}.*?[\'|"]{0,1})[\s|>]{1}/i', $body, $matches);
    for($i=0;$i<count($matches[0]);$i++)
    {
        $number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $matches[0][$i]);
        echo preg_replace('/<img.*?(src\=[\'|"]{0,1}.*?[\'|"]{0,1})[\s|>]{1}/i', '<img src="http://x.y/a/' . $number . '.png"', $matches[0][$i]);
    }
}
```

So if the page contains two files, one called 1.png and one called 2.png the script should parse the numbers and replace them with a different url such as `http://x.y/a/1.png` and `http://x.y/a/2.png`.

I've heard `preg_replace_callback` is the best way to do this but I have no idea how to get this working... Help!

Comment: Similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416425/preg-replace-preg-match-for-href-in-html-link

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Don't use regular expressions for irregular languages like HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357357/regexp-to-add-attribute-in-any-xml-tags/1357393#1357393). Use a [parser](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) instead. It will save you a lot of time and pain.

```
# Untested code:
$xml = new SimpleXml($xmlString);
foreach ($xml->xpath('//img') as $imgNode) {
    $imgNode->addAttribute('src', "http://x.y/a/" . $imgNode->getAttribute('src'));
}
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Note that you will need something like [`DOMDocument::loadHtml()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), if your html is not xhtml (i.e. valid xml), but the idea remains the same.

Comment: +1 regex is not at all suitable for processing [X][HT]ML. However shouldn't the XPath be `//img`? DOM getElementsByTagName would work fine too. I have no idea what the `stripslashes(html_entity_decode())` over the whole document is supposed to achieve in the original code; this will only mangle the document.

Comment: @bobince: Thanks for pointing out the '//img' error. I think the `stripslashes(...` part is for 'sanitizing' the value (which might be a good indication that the storage/retrieval of the document needs a re-design.)

Comment: -1 ignoring the specific question.. as a rule you don't want to use regexp, but he clearly stated that all the elements he wants to replace look exactly the same, so for this case, regexp is a better solution.

Comment: Ok, altered answer to exactly answer the specific question. But even if all img tags look the same, using RE is not a good idea for several reasons. 1.) The RE would even replace non-nodes (in javascript tags, for example). 2.) It is more error-prone and harder to debug, than the PHP code, thus 3.) it is harder to maintain than PHP code.

Comment: Seeing as you led me on the right track I'll mark this as accepted. Also thanks to TrueWill, that post has a good library which I've used to do what I needed to do. Thanks all. :-)

Comment: I know this is an old question, and a 2 year old answer, but this code doesn't work with the latest SimpleXML class in PHP. getAttribute() doesn't exist anymore, and addAttribute() doesn't replace an existing attribute. Just making a note for those who might stumble upon this question looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add the global replace flag "g" in your regex.

'/your_regex/i**g**'

As soulmerge suggested, Since your html is not malformed(I assume you mean it is well-formed XML), An XSLT transformation would be an effective way to alter anything in your document too. You could match on the @src attribute and alter it as per your requirements.

You can also match on any other tags / attributes if you need to alter some other parts of the document at the same time.