# PHP preg_match_all returns nothing

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to extract all **img** tags from an HTML string. See the code

```
$d1     = file_get_contents("http://itcapsule.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss");
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$d1,$result);
print_r($result);
```

And the result is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) )
```

But the same regex gives correct result in an online regex test tool http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/.

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

[Do not use regular expressions to process html, use a parser instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417795/replacing-image-src-in-html-tags/1417805#1417805)

Answer (score 1):

The content you are parsing is encoded with html entities - basically `<` is replaced with `&lt;`. Use [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)  first to convert the data into normal html.

PS: Use an HTML parser instead of regex.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using SimplePie XML Parser

```
include_once 'simplepie.inc';

$feed   = "feedurl";

$data       =   new SimplePie($feed);
$data->init();
$data->handle_content_type();

foreach ($data->get_items() as $item)
{
    $desc=$item->get_description();
    preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$desc,$result);
    print_r($result);
}
```

This is what exactly i was looking for :) Thanks guys !!