# SimpleXml class not found

Tags: php, simplexml

After initiating a new SimpleXml object:

```
$xml = new SimpleXML($xmlStr);
```

PHP errors out:

```
Fatal error: Class 'SimpleXML' not found
```

PHP info reads:

- Simplexml support    enabled
- Revision           $Revision:
  1.151.2.22.2.35.2.32 $
- Schema support       enabled

What could possibly be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `SimpleXMLElement`

Comment: Thanks, another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417795/replacing-image-src-in-html-tags threw me off as it uses SimpleXml, not SimpleXmlElement.

Answer (score 2):

To parse XML, use:

```
simplexml_load_string($string);
```

Or:

```
simplexml_load_file($filename);
```

These will each return SimpleXMLElement objects, as noted by others.

Comment: the constructor for SimpleXMLElement takes a data string too.