# preg_match for nested html tags

Tags: php, regex, nested, preg-match

I would like to catch all "dev" tags and their respective content, through php `preg_match_all()` but can't get the nested ones.

**data:**

`<dev>aaa</dev>`
`<dev>bbb</dev>`
`<dev>`
 `ccc`
`<dev>ddd</dev>`
`</dev>`

**my expression so far:**

`|<dev>(.*)</dev>|Uis`

thanks, for your help,
b.

Comment: Don’t use regular expression for parsing. Use a real parser instead.

Comment: Well, if s?he wants to parse a regular language it should be ok. But in general, yes. Especially so for HTML/XML and the like.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don’t use regular expressions for parsing. Use a real parser like [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/domdocument) or [SimpleXML](http://docs.php.net/simplexml):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<root>'.$str.'</root>');
```

Comment: Absolutely. There are several other examples at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417795/replacing-image-src-in-html-tags and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416425/preg-replace-preg-match-for-href-in-html-link

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a recursive matching pattern:

```
/<dev>(.*|(?R))<\/dev>/i
```

That will just suck up any nested elements, so if you want to then parse those, you will have to run the function again on $matches[1]

Comment: you should use / or # as your preg delimiter, the | (pipe) character is used to alternate matches

Answer (score -1):

The `*` is a greedy operator, consumes as many characters as possible. You should use the `*?` non-greedy version instead to find the smallest possible matches. Maybe regexes are not the best tools to do this.